# error 1001 an exception occurred during the commit phase

Tags: installation

I have an

> "Error 1001 An Exception occurred during the commit phase of the
>   installation. This exception will be ignored and installation will
>   continue. However, the application might not function correctly after
>   installation is complete"

while installing a program called "map-pit"
I am running an OS win 7 64 bit. I tried installing it on windows x-p and it worked!!
what could cause the problem?

Comment: I genuinely have no idea what map-git is, but I reckon you'd have to ask them. It sounds like a really specific product.

Comment: The tag is wrong (not git). Not sure what tag suggest.

Comment: suggestion for a tag please